# Error When Starting Cassandra for First Time

Tags: ubuntu, database, cluster, cassandra

I'm trying to get a single-node cluster of Cassandra set up on my VPS for a school project.  So I installed cassandra on Ubuntu 16.04 (JVM 1.8.0_161), but when I run, I encounter this error... https://pastebin.com/raw/h1vWhm2e

(Posted as link to provide full output).

I was just running it through the `cassandra` command.

Relevant bit:

```
    Exception (java.lang.AbstractMethodError) encountered during startup: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject(Ljava/rmi/Remote;ILjava/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory;Ljava/rmi/server/RMIServerSocketFactory;Lsun/misc/ObjectInputFilter;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject(Ljava/rmi/Remote;ILjava/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory;Ljava/rmi/server/RMIServerSocketFactory;Lsun/misc/ObjectInputFilter;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:150)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:135)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:405)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils.createJMXServer(JMXServerUtils.java:104)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:143)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:188)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:600)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:689)
ERROR [main] 2018-01-29 21:59:17,370 CassandraDaemon.java:706 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject(Ljava/rmi/Remote;ILjava/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory;Ljava/rmi/server/RMIServerSocketFactory;Lsun/misc/ObjectInputFilter;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:150) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:135) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:405) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils.createJMXServer(JMXServerUtils.java:104) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:143) [apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:188) [apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:600) [apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:689) [apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem, tracked as [CASSANDRA-14173](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14173) - until new release you need to downgrade Java to at least build 152

Comment: Wow, is this still the case? Amazing?